# do i want rolling_apply?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has a number of subjects completing a number of trials (1:800) and I want to add a "block" column...  There are 80 trials per block.  I feel like rolling_apply could be the solution, but I can't seem to make it work.

I could do some sort of thing were every value of "trial" between two increments gets set at a certain block, but it seems like rolling_apply should do this.  I'd really like to do this, but it isn't possible:

```
grouped = df.groupby('sid')
df['block'] = pd.rolling_cumcount(grouped, 80)
```

There are 10 blocks and 800 trials...

```
blocks = range(10)
increments = range(800)[0::80]
```

I have this:

```
  SID  Trial  
    1    0      
    1    1      
    1    2      
    1    3      
    1    4      
    1    5      
    2    0      
    2    1      
    2    2      
    2    3      
    2    4      
    2    5
```

What I want to end up with is (only I have 10 blocks, with 80 trials each):

```
SID  Trial  Block
1    0      0
1    1      0
1    2      0
1    3      1
1    4      1
1    5      1
2    0      0
2    1      0
2    2      0
2    3      1
2    4      1
2    5      1
```

Thanks

---

I ended up just doing this, which probably isn't an optimal solution, but works fine:

```
# add a block to each subject
block = np.arange(1,11)
block_array = np.repeat(block, 80)
blocks_all = np.tile(block_array, df['sid'].nunique())
df['block'] = blocks_all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use groupby's [cumcount](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items):

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby(['SID', 'Trial'])

In [12]: g.cumcount()
Out[12]: 
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     1
10    1
11    1
dtype: int64
```

And just set this to the column:

```
In [13]: df['Block'] = df.groupby(['SID', 'Trial']).cumcount()
```

Comment: I knew this was possible. Obviously I'm new at pandas - I appreciate the fast response!

Comment: Have fun with pandas, it's great! You might like to "accept" this answer if it's helped: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Actually, I didn't quite explain my question correctly.  I can't just cumcount() by "SID" and "Trial" because I want the first 80 trials to be "block" = 0, and then the next 80 trials to be "block" = 1 and so on, which is why I thought rolling_apply would be better.  I'll edit my post to reflect.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't follow. It sounds like maybe you can add another column, and groupby that too (and then cumcount) ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - i just went with that.  -K